# Celery revoke leaving zombie ffmpeg process

Tags: python, ffmpeg, operating-system, celery

We are using celery, rabbitmq and ffmpeg-python to read video streams. In a celery task (shared task), we are calling ffmpeg-python which internally uses subprocess to run ffmpeg.  Whenever we **revoke tasks** in celery, the ffmpeg processes become defunct/zombie. Over a time they start getting accumulated and exhausting our pids. Is there any way to gracefully exit the celery task along with its subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851411/graceful-shutdown-of-celery-workers) help you?

Quote:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('vwadaptor', broker='redis://workerdb:6379/0',backend='redis://workerdb:6379/0')
celery.control.broadcast('shutdown', destination=[<celery_worker_name>])
```

[EDIT]
Alternatively, [here](https://pypi.org/project/celery-graceful-stop/) is a python module that provides warm and cold shutdown behaviour on Celery. Disclaimer: I haven't used it.

Comment: No, I tried it but it is still leaving the zombie processes of ffmpeg

Comment: Is this also the case when running these processes natively on said os?

Comment: That is to say, does the error also occur when you run the FFMPEG process standalone, without celery/python involved.

Comment: No, it doesn't. We have resolved it by enclosing the code in try and except block and putting a terminate and wait for the subprocess in the finally block for clean up. Celery does not clean up the child process spawned gracefully with revoke.

Comment: Too bad but your solution is pretty elegant as well. Have you filed a bug with the creators of the module? If not, you probably could.